how can i transfer 10% to vault wallet and rest to winner anchor solana
I am trying to send 10% of winning to liquidity vault of the winning amount during claim prize and rest of 90% to winner.
Here is the anchor function
pub fn claim_prize(ctx: Context<ClaimPrize>, _lottery_id: u32, _ticket_id: u32) -> Result<()> {
        let lottery = &mut ctx.accounts.lottery;
        let ticket = &ctx.accounts.ticket;
        let winner = &ctx.accounts.authority;

        if lottery.claimed {
            return err!(LotteryError::AlreadyClaimed);
        }

        // Validate winner_id
        match lottery.winner_id {
            Some(winner_id) => {
                if winner_id != ticket.id {
                    return err!(LotteryError::InvalidWinner);
                }
            }
            None => return err!(LotteryError::WinnerNotChosen),
        };

        // Transfer the prize from Lottery PDA to the winner
        let prize = lottery
            .ticket_price
            .checked_mul(lottery.last_ticket_id.into())
            .unwrap();

        **lottery.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= prize;
        **winner.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += prize;

        lottery.claimed = true;

        msg!(
            "{} claimed {} lamports from lottery id {} with ticket id {}",
            winner.key(),
            prize,
            lottery.id,
            ticket.id
        );

        Ok(())
    }

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(lottery_id: u32)]
pub struct BuyTicket<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [LOTTERY_SEED.as_bytes(), &lottery_id.to_le_bytes()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub lottery: Account<'info, Lottery>,
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = buyer,
        space = 8 + 4 + 4 + 32,
        seeds = [
            TICKET_SEED.as_bytes(),
            lottery.key().as_ref(),
            &(lottery.last_ticket_id + 1).to_le_bytes()
        ],
        bump,
    )]
    pub ticket: Account<'info, Ticket>,
 
    #[account(mut)]
    pub buyer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

expectation is to transfer 10% to vault public key during claim.
lets say x34234324234 is the vault wallet and during claim prize 10% of winning should go to vault or liquidity wallet and rest to the winner. i am new to anchor and this is bothering me from multiple days.
